# Expo fonts not rendering while fonts are loaded

Tags: javascript, react-native, fonts

I have a certain issue where my fonts are correctly loaded but they are not rendered unless they are commented and then uncommented.
Here is a snippet of HomeScreen.js:

```js
 import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback }  from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View, ImageBackground ,TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Exercises from './Exercises';
import Flashcards from './Flashcards';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';


SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const HomeScreen = () => {
  

  let [isLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Typographica': require('nocram/assets/fonts/Typographica.ttf'),
    'NeulisAltRegular': require('nocram/assets/fonts/NeulisAlt-Regular.ttf'),
    'NeulisAltExtraBold': require('nocram/assets/fonts/NeulisAlt-ExtraBold.ttf'),
  });



  const handleOnLayout = useCallback(async () => {
    if (isLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync(); //hide the splashscreen
    }

  }, [isLoaded]);
```

The paths are correct and 'isLoaded' has true as a value.
I am using the following packages:

```json
{
  "name": "nocram",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleOnLayout = useCallback(async () => {
if (isLoaded) {
  await SplashScreen.hideAsync(); //hide the splashscreen
}}, [isLoaded]);
```

You have used **useCallback** that means **a function** so you need to **trigger** it in somewhere. Maybe you can use only **useEffect** for this. That would be usefull.

Comment: I am very thankful for your kind response. Nonetheless, it seems that I forgot to add the instance of use which was <View onLayout={handleOnLayout}> in my code snippet. Fortunatly I found a solution to this problem through the use of if (isLoaded ) as a condition for the return value, as this allowed the proper rendering of the fonts.